# How can I use lubridate parsing function with a R pipeline?

Tags: r, datetime, pipeline, lubridate

I'm trying to write a pipeline that parses a date vector and subtracts 4 hours from each value. Here's some sample data:

```
structure(list(Created = c("24/04/2019 05:03:45", "24/04/2019 05:03:47", 
"24/04/2019 05:03:56", "24/04/2019 05:04:00", "24/04/2019 11:51:57", 
"24/04/2019 05:58:21", "23/04/2019 10:36:24", "24/04/2019 01:33:53", 
"23/04/2019 18:44:50", "23/04/2019 18:25:19"), Ended = c("Â", 
"Â", "Â", "Â", "24/04/2019 12:20:26", "24/04/2019 11:51:57", 
"23/04/2019 10:51:21", "24/04/2019 05:03:56", "24/04/2019 01:33:53", 
"23/04/2019 18:44:50")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This works:

```
Data$Ended <- dmy_hms(Data$Ended)
Data$Ended <- Data$Ended - hours(4)
```

But this first step doesn't:

```
Data$Ended %>% dmy_hms()
```

I get this Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: I am not sure how to create a list sorry. Essentially 23-04-2019 01:00:00 would become 22-04-2019 21:00:00 parsed as a date-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such kind of transformation you've better use `mutate()`
And pipeline framework allow you to avoid using Data$ for each field.
If we pretend that Data looks like this, you can try:

```
Data <- tibble(Ended=c('23-04-2019 00:00:00', '23-04-2019 01:00:00', 
                       '24-04-2019 00:00:00', '24-04-2019 01:00:00'))

Data <- Data %>% 
  mutate(Ended=dmy_hms(Ended)- hours(4))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but won't mutate add a new column? I just want to reformat the existing values

Comment: if you use constructions like `Ended=dmy_hms(Ended)`, `mutate()` reformat your existing field.

Comment: with example of Data I used in answer, `Data$Ended %>% dmy_hms()` is working well. So in order to answer your question, some example of real data needed.

Comment: I have warning message `Warning message:  4 failed to parse.` because of "Â" that can't be converted to date, but my solution is working. NA returned in 4  first rows. Have you tried it?
BTW you code `Data$Ended %>% dmy_hms()` gives similar result, but it returns vector, not a dataframe.